# How to upload multiple images to server using alamofire in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to upload multiple images to server using alamofire.I have used belwo code for this purpose.But the issue is i don't how i pass the filename & parameter name for file.I don't know how to implement it.

```
func uploadMultiImage(_ method:Method,domainName: String, parameters:Parameters?, encoding:Encoding, headers: [String:String]?,imageData:Data)-> Void  {
    print("header is \(headers)")


    Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: completeURL(domainName: domainName), method: method, headers: headers).uploadProgress(closure: {

        progress in

        self.progress(progress.fractionCompleted)
        }
        ).responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in

            print("response is \(response.description)")
            print("response1 is \(response.debugDescription)")
            print("response2 is \(response.result.description)")



        })
}
```

Please guide which is the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if let img = selectImageOutlet.image {

// IMAGE_SHAKE_BASE_URL = "https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"
let imageShackUrl = NSURL(string: IMAGE_SHAKE_BASE_URL)!

//Convert to jpeg & compress by 80%(0.2)
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!

let keyData = IMAGE_SHACK_API_KEY.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let keyJson = "json".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

Alamofire.upload(.POST, imageShackUrl, multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

    MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyData, name: "key")
    MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imgData, name: "fileupload", fileName: "image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyJson, name: "format")

    },encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

        switch encodingResult {

        case .Success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                if let info = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    if let links = info["links"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        if let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                            print("LINK: \(imgLink)")
                        }
                    }
                }

            } case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
        }
})}
```

http://blog.mingweitee.com/2016/04/09/swift-how-to-upload-images-using-alamofire/

Comment: in this way i can't track progress that how much % image is uploaded ?

Comment: Yes u can. check this link  http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-with-progress-bar-example-in-swift/